# Join value from type="text" & type="time" to store it as timstamp in php, Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

From an form I'm receiving a date value and time value via Ajax post.
Now i want to combine them to store them as timestamp value in MySQL.
how can i join them?

Comment: a way to join $_POST["activeDate"] and $_POST["activeTime"] from <input type="date" name="activeDate" /> & <input type="time" name="activeTime" /> respectively so that i store them in activeAt in mysql database as timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Let's say

```
$date = $_POST['activeDate'];
$time = $_POST['activeTime'];
$timeStamp = strtotime($date.$time);
```

`strtotime()` is used to convert date string into timestamp.
`$timeStamp` is your timestamp. You can test `date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$timeStamp)` to check of it's working properly. Another way of doing this is to use `<input type="datetime-local">` combined input to get both the values

Comment: Found this plugin https://flatpickr.js.org/ it solved my problem